# Graphics Card Not Avalible in Blender Internal

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, gpu

For some reason Blender does not use my GPU when rendering, even though I have my card selected in the user preferences [image]

When I render, my CPU usage goes up to 100% and MSI Afterburner shows no increase of GPU usage. It also doesn't show an option to change my compute device in the system area or whatever [image]

However, when I switch to Cycles Render, it gives me the option to use my GPU, but not when I am in normal Blender Render. Is there a way to fix this or is it set like this for some reason? [image]

Comment: Blender Internal was designed to render using CPU, currently it cannot make advantage of using GPU for rendering, thats why there is no option for that.

Comment: @Denis That should be an answer, not a comment. Comments are for clarification.

Answer (score 5):

**GPU Rendering is not available for Blender Internal**

Blender Internal engine was designed to use CPU long before GPU rendering was available. To make the use of GPU in Blender Internal it will be necessary to rewrite the code of this rendering engine in order to adapt to different computation technology, currently it is not in the priority of the developers, but hopefully in the future.

Comment: Highly doubtful, all the focus is currently on Cycles, and Internal has not been updated in a long time. I believe it's being phased out at the moment since cycles is a superior engine.

Comment: I wouldn't ever expect to see BI ported to GPU. It's an old rendering engine and will probably be replaced with the new viewport work. @meed96 It probably won't be going anywhere for a while, but there won't be much development.

Comment: @meed96 Blender Internal had minor updates recently in the node editor, and there is no reason that it should be phased out since it has some advantages with much faster non-realistic rendering than cycles.

Comment: @Denis I'm not saying I made the decision to do it, but I do support it. I'm just saying that's the way it is. Also, the node editor is for Cycles?

Comment: @meed96 There is node editor in Blender Internal too for making complex materials.