# Render Blender's Internal Halo Material with GPU?

Tags: rendering, gpu

Is it possible to render the Blender Internal's halo material with an Nvidia GPU instead of the CPU?

Answer (score 1):

Blender Internal is designed to use CPU, not GPU, thus making this impossible... for now

Related:

[Graphics Card Not Avalible in Blender Internal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28787/graphics-card-not-avalible-in-blender-internal)

Comment: Ok, but is it impossible to recode it to use the GPU? It seems impossible that no one tried to recode it...

Comment: This question has been asked many times. Blender will one day most likely recode it .You could maybe search the web for a better answer on this.